# Why does my Laravel installation need prefixing \ backslash for facades aliases

Tags: laravel-5, alias, laravel-facade

I don't know the reason for malfunction of the following example:

```
Auth::user()->id
```

However, just prefixing it with backslash makes it works fine:

```
\Auth::user()->id
```

This is a snippet from `config/app.php`

```
'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
```

The server is Apache on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [how namespaces work](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).

When you're in a typical Laravel model, controller, etc., you're within its namespace - something like `App` or `App\Http\Controllers` or whatnot. As such, `Auth::foo()` means `App\Auth::foo()` or `App\Http\Controllers\Auth::foo()`, respectively.

This is why [the examples that teach you how to use Auth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication) all do `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` before they use the `Auth` class, and say things like:

> We will access Laravel's authentication services via the `Auth` facade, so we'll need to make sure to import the `Auth` facade at the top of the class.

Comment: Very good note I had not aware before i.e using App\Http... In the documentation examples.